# Tomcat in ISO-8859-15 cannot write filenames with latin characters

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding, filenames

We have a tomcat using file.encoding=ISO-8859-15 and we cannot change it because we use some external libraries and only works in ISO-8859-15.

When we write a file, the content is save correctly but the filename does not.

We need store the content of the file in ISO-8859-15 (the tomcat default started with -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-15 -Duser.language=es -Duser.region=ES -Duser.country=ES) but when we try to save a file with the name "áéíóú.txt", it write the file as ?????.txt and the content.

I've tried by changing the -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 but it does not work. We use jdk 1.6.

Curiously it works if I start the tomcat with the same parameters (and the same system properties) from Eclipse in my Ubuntu 15.10, but not in CentOS release 6.4.

Comment: Try unpacking a zip containing a such a file in a console. Probably under CentOS you have only ASCII. A linux question.

Comment: If I run a small java application in UTF-8 and write the áéíóú.txt file, it works, the problem is creating the file from the tomcat started with file.encoding=ISO-8859-15

Comment: What about "Windows-1252" which is close. You could try to write the filename to a simple text file, together with `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`. If its content does not contain ???? then the file system for the TomCat user is somehow wrong. Also where does the filename stem from? Hard-coded can go wrong, JSP can, DB can.

Comment: I know, the tomcat System.getProperty("file.encoding") is ISO-8859-15 but the system encoding is UTF-8 that is the problem. If I write the filename into a text file, I can read it correctly but not in the filename itself

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
LANG="es_ES.iso885915@euro"
```

to the Tomcat configuration file (in CentOS, it should be `/etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf`) and restart it. If you prefer a slightly different coding system (such as "es_ES.iso88591") `locale -a` lists those available in your system.

BTW, maybe using LANG you can avoid setting `-Duser.language` (as well as region and country).